Definition of closure of operator
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $A:\mathrm{dom}(A)\to\mathcal{H}$ be an unbounded operator. I have seen the following definition of the closure in a lecture:
$$\mathrm{dom}(\overline{A})=\{x\in\mathcal{H}\mid \exists (x_{n})_{n}\in\mathcal{D}(A) \text{ s.t. }x_{n}\to x \text{ and }A x_{n} \text{ is convergent}\}$$
and then one sets $\overline{A}x:=\lim_{n\to\infty} A x_{n}$. However, does this definition agree with the standard one? With the standard one I mean $\mathrm{dom}(\overline{A})$ is the set of all elements $x\in\mathcal{H}$ such that there exists a $y\in\mathcal{H}$ with the property that for every sequence $x_{n}\to x$ it holds that $Ax_{n}\to y$. One then sets $\overline{A}x:=y$.
One direction of the equivalence is clear, the other not so much.

The two definitions are indeed equivalent: This can easily be seen by considering the definition of the closure of an operator in terms of the graph: Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $A:\mathcal{D}(A)\to\mathcal{H}$ be a linear operator (possibly unbounded). Its graph is the linear subspace
$$\mathcal{G}(A):=\{(x,Ax)\mid x\in\mathcal{D}(A)\}\subset\mathcal{H}\oplus\mathcal{H}.$$
Now, an operator $A$ is called closable if and only if there exists a linear operator $\overline{A}$ whose graph is $\overline{\mathcal{G}(A)}$. This operator is clearly uniquely defined (since $\mathcal{G}(A)=\mathcal{G}(B)$ for two operators $A$ and $B$ if and only if $A=B$) and is called the closure of $A$. Now, let us give an explicit characterization of the closure $\overline{A}$:
Assume that $A$ is closable. Then, $(x,y)\in\mathcal{G}(\overline{A})=\overline{\mathcal{G}(A)}$ if and only if there exists sequences $x_{n},y_{n}$ in $\mathcal{D}(A)$ such that $x_{n}\to x$ and $y_{n}\to y$. In other words, by definition of the graph, $x\in\mathcal{D}(\overline{A})$ if and only if there exists a sequence $x_{n}$ in $\mathcal{D}(A)$ such that $x_{n}\to x$ and $A x_{n}\to y$. We then set $\overline{A}x:=\lim_{n\to\infty}Ax$. Note that this is well-defined (i.e. independent of the chosen sequence) thanks to the following little Lemma:

Lemma: A linear subspace $\mathcal{S}$ of $\mathcal{H}\oplus\mathcal{H}$ is a graph of a linear operator if and only if $(0,y)\in\mathcal{S}$ for some $y\in\mathcal{H}$ implies $y=0$.

Proof. Assume there exists a linear operator $A:\mathcal{D}(A)\to\mathcal{H}$ whose graph is $\mathcal{S}$. Then $(0,y)\in\mathcal{S}$ for some $y\in\mathcal{H}$ clearly implies $y=0$ since $y=A 0=0$, by linearity. On the other hand, if $(0,y)\in\mathcal{S}$ for some $y\in\mathcal{H}$ implies $y=0$, we define a linear operator $A$ by $A x:=y$ for every pair $(x,y)\in\mathcal{S}$.
Note that the previous Lemma and the definition of the closure actually implies the following:

Lemma: A linear operator $A$ is closable if and only if for every sequence $x_{n}$ in $\mathcal{H}$ such that $x_{n}\to 0$ and $A x_{n}\to y$ for some $y\in\mathcal{H}$, it follows that $y=0$.

Now, this Lemma also shows why your second definition is equivalent: Let $A$ be a closable operator. Then, for any two sequences $x_{n},x^{\prime}_{n}$ in $\mathcal{D}(A)$, which converge to $x\in\mathcal{H}$ and for which $Ax_{n}\to y$ and $A x_{n}^{\prime}\to y^{\prime}$ for $y,y^{\prime}\in\mathcal{H}$ it follows that $y=y^{\prime}$.
Proof. The sequence $x_{n}-x_{n}^{\prime}$ clearly converges to zero. Furthermore, the sequence $A(x_{n}-x_{n}^{\prime})$ is convergent with limit given by $y-y^{\prime}$, by linearity. Hence, the previous Lemma implies $y-y^{\prime}=0$.
So, long story short: In order to be able to even talk about the closure of an operator, you need the requiement that $A$ is closable. But this is exactly equivalent to require that the limits of two convergent sequences of the form $A x_{n},A x_{n}^{\prime}$ with $x_{n},x_{n}^{\prime}\to x$ are the same and hence garuantees the equivalence of your two definitions.
